# Parse JSON Object that contains Json string

Tags: javascript, json

I want to parse a JSON Object that contains  some value as a json string, note that I don't know those fields previously, so I can't do something like
`obj[key]=JSON.parse(obj[key])`. I am looking for an easy way to do that,

```
obj={
  Name:"{\"FirstName\":\"Douglas\",\"LastName\":\"Crockford\"}"
}
```

And I want to get

```
{
  Name:{
      FirstName:"Douglas",
      LastName:"Crockford"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll write a handy little utility which maps a function over object properties:

```
function mapObject(obj, fn) {
  const result = {};
  for (const prop in obj) result[prop] = fn(obj[prop], prop);
  return result;
}
```

Now you can create an object with all the JSON values in the input parsed by just saying

```
mapObject(obj, JSON.parse)
```

If you want to guard against property values which are not valid JSON, then

```
function parseJSON(x) {
  try { return JSON.parse(x); }
  catch (e) { return x; }
}
```

and then

```
mapObject(obj, parseJSON)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get paradoxical about it, you can handle arbitrarily nested versions of this scenario using the ["reviver parameter"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#reviver). Start by `stringifying` your object!

```
function parseJSON(k,v) {
  try { return JSON.parse(v, parseJSON); }
  catch(e) { return v; }
}
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), parseJSON);
```

Is that nifty, or is it just me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.keys(obj)` to get the property names to allow you to use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Yeah thanks, I thought that i could have more pretty solution but I see that this is what I can do

Comment: and I must use try and catch , in case some value are not in json format

Answer (score 0):

You can always try/pass on every key:

```js
a = {
  a: 1,
  b: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}),
  c: 'asdf'
}
console.log(a);
new_a = {}
Object.keys(a).map((key) => {
  try {
    new_a[key] = JSON.parse(a[key]);
  } catch(err) {
    new_a[key] = a[key];
  }
})

console.log(new_a);
```

Comment: Purists would say that this is a misuse of `map`, and should be `forEach`. Their logic would be that `map` is designed for transforming one array into another, and should not be used for its side-effects, such as mutating the input.

Comment: I will do that with foreach , it's more convenient

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop over all the keys:

```js
obj={
  Name: "{\"FisrtName\":\"Douglas\",\"LastName\":\"Crockford\"}",
  Other: "This isn't JSON"
};
for (var key in obj) {
    try {
        obj[key] = JSON.parse(obj[key]);
    } catch(err) {
        // ignore error, just leave it alone
    }
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: There will be a problem in case some of the values are not valid json strings

Comment: I thought all the values were JSON, didn't see "some" in the question.

Comment: From the question; "note that I don't know those fields previously, so I can't do something like  obj[key]=JSON.parse(obj[key])"

Comment: Like I said, I didn't notice that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: well... now the answer is exactly as mine :)

Comment: @Dekel I use `for`, you use `map`.

Comment: Yeah thanks for remember me the try and catch in those case of parsing

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded with :
jsonData['key']['value']

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).